# Oracle Regex Exclude a Word (Only if it is found)

Tags: oracle, regex-negation, word-boundary

**SOFTWARE:** Oracle

---

---

I have a query that matches

`EXCEL.EXE` to `EXCEL.EXE`

`Dropbox.exe` to `Dropbox.exe`

`1-2-3-4-hike.exe` to `1-2-3-4-hike.exe`

`shish boom bah.exe` to `bah.exe`

`MS Outlook` to `MS Outlook`

However, I wish to exclude the `.exe`.

---

In other words

`EXCEL.EXE` to `EXCEL`

`Dropbox.exe` to `Dropbox`

`1-2-3-4-hike.exe` to `1-2-3-4-hike`

`shish boom bah.exe` to `bah`

`MS Outlook` to `MS Outlook`

---

Here is a previous working query:

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(M.ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME, '\.exe', 'i')
     THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(M.ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME,'[a-zA-Z0-9]\S*\.exe',1,1,'i')
     ELSE M.ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME
END
```

And here is my incorrect modified query - been trying `!(.exe)` among other things -- Please guide

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(M.ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME, '\.exe', 'i')
     THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(M.ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME,'[a-zA-Z0-9]\S*\!(.exe)',1,1,'i')
     ELSE M.ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME
END
```

Comment: What about simple `replace( some_string, '.exe', '')` ?

Comment: Hello @krokodilko I shall try this and follow up --- thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex capturing groups, with a group (parentheses) around your desired substring. For example:

```
with test_vals AS (
    SELECT 'EXCEL.EXE' AS ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Dropbox.exe' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT '1-2-3-4-hike.exe' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'shish boom bah.exe' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'MS Outlook' FROM dual
)

SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(M.ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME, '\.exe', 'i')
           THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(
                  M.ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME,'([a-zA-Z0-9]\S*)\.exe',1,1,'i',1 /* Only return result of first capturing group */
               )
           ELSE M.ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME
       END
FROM test_vals m
```